# Filter tiles view of a Document Library in modern sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, modern-experience, tiles

I have a document library in a modern SharePoint on which I use custom formatting to customize the tiles view. The library contains leaning material for the users in different languages.

The document library is embedded on our Site Collection's main page. I want the users, when they arrive on the main page, to be able to filter the included document library by language.

Currently I can include the document library with the tiles view **on the main page**. But using the tiles view there is no possibility for users to set a filter. The filter is only available when I use the **list view**. When I go to the **document library** there is a filter icon which I can click on to filter the tiles view.

Is there a possibility for users to filter the **tiles view** on the **main page**?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could add a Highlighted content web part in the site collection main page to filter documents.

Reference: [Use the Highlighted content web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd)

Comment: Yes. But then I filter the content and I need the users to apply the filter relevant to them.